# how can LASSO fit a worse model given more predictors

Tags: lasso, regularization

I have a problem that when I offer LASSO more predictors it gives a worse model than when I offer fewer - and it doesn't even pick those additional variables in the worse model.

eg when I offer variables A + B + C + D + E  LASSO is (say) picking a model  with  A,B,C,D (shrinking effect of E to zero) and I get (say)  an AUC of 70% (on a 1/3 holdout test set)

But when I offer A + B + C + D + E + F + G + H it picks a smaller model (say A and B) and has a worse AUC (say 65%) on the holdout data.

And it doesn't even pick those additional variables F and G

This seems odd to me.

Comment: Is $\lambda$ fixed?

Comment: ah, no I use cv.glmnet to pick the "best" lambda each time (likely different) by cross validation, thnks for your help

Comment: what's the correllation of G and H with teh other features in the model?

Comment: thanks, Ben - actually they aren't that correlated - I should say that two of F,G,H are binary though. Some of A-F are quite intercorrelated (not all)

Comment: actually I thought LASSO was designed to handle correlated predictors well - I mean without giving results that might be thought odd

Comment: I think this needs more detail to be answerable